# Store pointer in c in a specific register

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, cpu-registers

Is there anyway I can load a c pointer into a specific register like eax? I want to take an array, like int array[10], and load array (or &array[0], but either way they're the same thing) into register eax.

Comment: Which compiler do you use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is compiler dependent. Gcc has an extension to the `register` keyword

```
register unsigned* p __asm__("eax") = a;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm using GCC so that's perfect. Also, is there any way to store a register value in a c variable? Like grab eax's value and put it in some non-register c variable?

Comment: Just use the variable `p` as in this example without initialization and assign its value to whatever you want. `p` and the `eax` register are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can store C pointer into the register if the register location can able to access. and the register size is Enough to store the pointer value.pointers size is varies between different processors. check the size and then try.

If the register is byte accessible then directly place the value of pointer in the byte locations. if bit accessible then you need to shifting and then need to store overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the inline assembly, which can be defined by `__asm/__asm__` keywords (MSVC/GCC), but it is not portable way. 
   For example:

   `int arr[10];
    __asm { mov eax, DWORD PTR arr }`

   Note: modern x64 compilers prohibit to use inline assembly
2. You can also use `register` keyword, but there is no guarantee that compiler will place pointer in eax register exactly